# iOS real time 2 players app

Tags: ios, swift, real-time, matchmaking

I am currently writing an iOS real time game app auto-matchmaking function. I really need help to find out how can the two players can interact. Specifically, when plaeryA pressed the find match button indicating playerA is looking for a match. It sends a query to Parse database and sees that playerB is is also looking for a match. Now, I want them to be matched. I know it is a very bad idea to use queries to frequently polling the data from the database to check if the player is matched or not. Is there anyway I can achieve it such that 'if A and B is matched, a notification/alert is sent to both players to wait for their acceptance, if A & B both accepted the match, then the two players would perform the segue to the game view controller simultaneously.

I googled online, all I got is that I have to either use Apple's Game Center or Google Play service. But both of them requires users login. I do not really want that because it would be tedious user experience. The user had to register and sign in the account of my app, and now they have to sign in either game center or google again.

Any advice/help is greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Game Center sign in is automatic.

Comment: not if it's the first time though...

Comment: Use cloud kit with subscriptions, that would work.